# How can I filter messages by contact on Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there a way I can group my Microsoft Outlook email messages by person I'm interacting with? (kind of like a CRM?)

For instance, I'd like to have a list of my contacts, then click on the name or email of a contact and have Outlook list all of the messages I exchanged with that person.

Is there a way I can do that?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is make a separate folder for each contact. You can do this by using rules; it may depend on which version of outlook you're using but on my one (the desktop version) I go to the home tab and find rules in there.

In the online version, after clicking on the check box of an email, I go the little icon with three horizontal dots, choose 'create new rule', then under 'do the following', choose 'move to' and select a folder to send that contacts emails to.

Then in the left column you'll have a separate folder for each contact and you could then click on the folder for the corresponding contact and all of their emails will be there.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer but that is not exactly what I'm looking for. I use folders and rules a lot. But it is not that simple. If had just a few contacts it could be, but imagine I have hundreds and all of the time new ones keep coming. It's impractical to have a folder for each one. One thing I found that is closer to what I'm looking for is the People Pane. But unfortunately it shows just the emails sent by the person, not the emails I sent to that person as well. thanks